# Distinct values of a CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How do I get the first X distinct combinations of an Oracle SQL CROSS JOIN such that: if a row with values `(a, b)` exists, there are no other columns within X that repeat `a` or `b`?

In my example, I have two tables with `1000 * 1000 = 1,000,000` combinations - but I only want the first 500 unique pairs. These seem to occur at ROWNUM = 1, 1001, 2001, 3001, etc.

I have a Customers and Books table - and I want to generate 500 random book sales [a table which references both customers/books as FKs] such that there are 500 unique customers, and 500 unique books. I have done a cross join of Customers to Books, but this gives a cartesian product of all book/customer combinations. How do I get 500 unique customers, and 500 unique books?

Thanks.

Comment: `I only want the first 500 unique pairs` ... what is the logic or data to support your requirement?

Comment: I have a Customers and Books table - and I want to generate 500 random book sales [a table which references both customers/books as FKs] such that there are 500 unique customers, and 500 unique books. I have done a cross join of Customers to Books, but this gives a cartesian product of all book/customer combinations. How do I get 500 unique customers, and 500 unique books?

Comment: then they are not "random" book sales but a carefully triaged set of book sales

Comment: OK, then how do I use SQL to generate this carefully triaged set of book sales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use analytic functions here.  In the approach below, I am retaining the "first" `b` record for every group of `a` records having the same value:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ta.a, tb.b, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ta.a) dr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ta.a ORDER BY tb.b) rn
    FROM Tablea ta
    CROSS JOIN Tableb tb
)

SELECT a, b
FROM cte
WHERE dr = rn;
```